Compliance for App Using Apple Pay for Donations
I’m working on an app that would allow users to donate to certified associations. The app provides a list of associations, where each one is individually verified before being displayed. Users can select an association and donate directly to its bank account via Apple Pay.
I’ve already reached out to Apple Support to confirm whether this setup complies with their App Store guidelines. However, I haven’t yet received a clear or detailed response, so I’m turning to the community for advice.
From what I understand, donations to certified associations are generally permitted with Apple Pay. However, our case is slightly unique:
1.  The app features multiple associations.
2.  The app developers (us) are not directly part of these associations.

Has anyone here developed a similar app or encountered comparable scenarios? Are there specific guidelines or requirements we should follow to ensure compliance with App Store policies?
Any advice or experiences you can share would be greatly appreciated!
